# Renaming columns in DataFrame when column names are the same

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have a DataFrame which looks like the following:

```
df
              a    a    a   b
date                              
2004-01-01    30   10   3   1
2004-01-02    30   14   4   2
2004-01-03    31   15   5   3
2004-01-04    30   15   6   3
2004-01-05    30   15   7   3
```

I want to rename the first `a` to one, the second `a` to two, the third `a` to three and `b` to four. I am not sure how to do this!

Cheers :)

Comment: As you're intending to overwrite all the columns then the first answer in the dupe suffices

Comment: Use `pip` to install the `num2words` package.  `from num2words import num2words`, then use list comprehension to assign new column names: `df.columns = [num2words(x + 1) for x in np.arange(df.shape[1])]`